# Java Spring MVC non-web accessable file storage

Tags: java, spring, persistence

I want to be able to store (and append to and later retrieve) files within my Web Application in a portable manner (so not an absolute path for a given server) that is also never web accessible (even if the webapp its self is removed/broken, so not dependent on Java/xml config to block a GET request for some url).

An SQL BLOB or TEXT field or filesystem file is fine, as long as lots of appends can be pushed efficiently.

Comment: Why not use an FTP server ? host it on an internal network so you won't rely on xml config to block the GET requests.

Comment: and wen i want to append 100bytes to a large file? I have to download it, add 100bytes and upload it again?

Answer (score 0):

Use a database.
Define a table with two columns: order and value.
Make order an automatically incrementing sequence
(most databases, including MySQL have this).
Use max length for value (often 255 chars for a varchar).

BLOBs and CLOBs are often overkill if you just want rows in insert order.